# How to get the title of the selected UIAlertController of type action sheet for iOS 8.0+ into a label?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have created a drop down with text and button, when the drop down button is clicked the data is populated in the `UIAlertController` of type action sheet.

Now to replicate drop down behavior  need to set the text of textfield as the clicked `UIAlertActon` title.

But I am not able to find any way to fetch the title and set it as text of `UITextField`. I am using swift.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please post your code so we know what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `UIAlertAction`, you can add a handler which gets called when the button is tapped. Your action gets passed into the handler, so you can access its title property there:

```
let myAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: .Default) { action in
    println(action.title)
}
```

You can see this in the [docs for UIAlertAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class).